# Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$, then exists $c$ s.t. $f(c)=c$.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a function such that
$$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$$
for all $x,y\in X$. Show that there exists $c\in X$ such that $f(c)=c$.

**Remark:** Initially I thought that it was a simple consequence of Banach's fixed point theorem, but everything is complicated because I can not associate this theorem with this problem.

Comment: Type "fixed point in compact metric space" in the Search in the top bar and hit Enter, to see an initial segment of an infinite sequence of duplicates of this Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By contradiction suppose that for all $x\in X$ we have $f(x)\neq x$. Therefore, we consider the function $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ defined by
$$g(x)=d(f(x),x).$$
Note that $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in X$ and $g$ is continuous (becasue $f$ is continuous and triangle inequality), then there exists $c\in X$ such that $g(c)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ (because $X$ is compact and $f$ continuous). But by hypotesis we have
$$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y).$$
Then 
$$g(f(c))=d(f(f(c)),f(c))<d(f(c),c)=g(c).$$
This is a contradiction.

Comment: Why $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Because $|x-y|< \delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y| < \delta$.

Comment: @Frost By inverse triangle inequality for $d$ you have \begin{align}|d(f(x),x)-d(f(y),y)|&=|d(f(x),x)-d(f(y),x)-(d(f(y),y)-f(f(y),x))|\\&\leq|d(f(x),x)-d(f(y),x)|+|d(f(y),y)-d(f(y),x)|\\&\leq d(f(y),f(x))+d(y,x)\\&\leq 2d(y,x). \end{align}